# mysqli_multi_query executes only the first query, what seems to be lacking?

Tags: mysqli

$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['user'][0]);
        $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($link);

```
    mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);

    //make the string
    $sql = "INSERT INTO district (DistID, Dist, UserID) VALUES(NULL, '".$dist->getDist()."', '".$userid."');";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO lok (LocID, Loc, DistID) VALUES(NULL, '".$loc->getLokal()."','".$lastid."');";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO schedule (SchedID, Mon, LocID) 
                VALUES(NULL, '".$sched->getMon()."', '".$lastid."')";

    // execute query
    if ($result = mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql)){
        do {
            if ($result = mysqli_use_result($link)) {
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        } while (mysqli_next_result($link));

        mysqli_commit($link);

    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_rollback($link);
    }
        mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: I have change my code and used mysqli_use_result but it still gives me the same result. When I check my database only the first query was executed.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [mysqli_use_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) or [mysqli_store_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) for the results of the first query.

Comment: I have change my code and use mysqli_use_result but it still gives me the same result. When I check my database only the first query was executed. Maybe I'm using it or placing the statement in the wrong place. Please show me how.